# Cannot manage services on remote server, how to remotely execute without services?

Tags: rdp, remote-access, windows-service

#### Background info

I am in a bit of a situation right now.
One of our clients has an application server (`Server 2008 R2`) which hosts critical medical applications. The server is located in another city, no display attached. It is in a domain network I have access to remotely via VPN and RDP, though. Now today it would not start one of the applications, and when trying to RDP into the machine I got a timeout, while I can ping it and network shares are still available.
Looking further into it, RDP and VNC services are not running. I can still use remote management and try to start/stop/restart services on the server, but it fails with error 1053, stating basically a timeout happened. Now normally I would just reboot but here this isn't an option currently.

#### The question

So due my inability to start services, I can't even use PSExec to regain remote access. Is there any possibility to start an application remotely without being dependent on a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a program requires a service to run properly then the answer is No, the service is a must.

As for RDP, since the service is responsible for opening RDP port (3389) for listening then I believe that you won't be able to connect to the remote machine until the service is up and port is opened.

Edit #1:

PsExec uses the Windows Service control Manager API to start the PsExecsvc service on the remote system which creates a named pipe that PsExec communicates with. This named pipe is what allows for input/output redirection back to the system that launched PsExec.

You can try using PowerShell, follow [this guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx) to do so.

If both PowerShell and `psexec` are not working for you then as far as I know there are no other ways to run commands on remote machines.

Comment: Well no, I'd like to start an UltraVNC server, which is just an application able to run standalone. That way, I could open a remote session.

Comment: Please check Edit #1.

Comment: well thank you then, guess I'm going on a road trip.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck :)